# How to configure Redis 3.4 and above in master/slave config to resolve error Sentinel running on protected mode?

Tags: redis

I am working with **Redis 3.2** and while connecting to the sentinel from a differnt machine I get the following error:

```
Trying X.X.X.X...
Connected to X.X.X.X.
Escape character is '^]'.
-DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password is requested to clients. In this mode connections are only accepted from the loopback interface. If you want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions: 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the server. 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one of the above things in order for the server to start accepting connections from the outside.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Can somene help me resolve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From redis 3.2, Sentinel by default, is not reachable from interfaces other than localhost.

Either use the 'bind' directive to bind to a list of network interfaces, or disable protected mode with "protected-mode no" by adding it to this configuration file.

For example you may use one of the following:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.1

protected-mode no
```

Comment: This answer really helped in my project.

Comment: I have 3 node master/replica setup. My config file has protected mode on and bind to ip address ex: bind 127.0.0.1 172.xx.xx.xx and it was working. When server reboots  it stops working and i have to change bind to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 6):

For testing, you can try

```
redis-server --protected-mode no
```

This will set Redis protected mode to no.

As from documentation suggested steps.

> 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET
>   protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis
>   from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is
>   not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE
>   to make this change permanent.
>
> 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing
>   the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to
>   'no', and then restarting the server.
>
> 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it
>   with the '--protected-mode no' option.
>
> 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only
>   need to do one of the above things in order for the server to start
>   accepting connections from the outside.